# How to stop P5 input from being covered by P5 objects?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm fairly new to P5 and I want to create an input field that is sometimes hidden, but when shown, appears in a div with some text. The issue is the div is drawn in front of the button, and using .show() still doesn't put it in front, any help greatly appreciated.

```js
let borderHeight = 800;
let borderWidth = 1500;
let fixedSupportArray = [];
let rollingSupportArray = [];
let verticalForces = [];
let moments = [];
let wallSupports = [false, false];
var simpleSupportDiv;
var wallSupportDiv;
var simpleSupportDivShown = false;
var wallSupportDivShown = false;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(borderWidth, borderHeight);

  // default values
  let beamLength = 5;

  // creating border lines
  strokeWeight(4);
  stroke(0);
  fill(220);
  rect(0,0,borderWidth,borderHeight);

  // creating title
  fill(0);
  textSize(32);
  strokeWeight(1);
  text("Static Beam Analysis",borderWidth/2-150,40);

  // creating input texts
  textSize(16);
  strokeWeight(0);
  text("Enter Beam Length",10,25);
  text("Select Support Type",10,75);
  text("Select Force Type",10,220);

  // creating input fields

  beamLengthInput = createInput('5');
  beamLengthInput.position(155,12);
  beamLengthInput.size(32,14);

  beamLengthUnitsInput = createSelect();
  beamLengthUnitsInput.position(202,12);
  beamLengthUnitsInput.size(35,20);
  beamLengthUnitsInput.option("km");
  beamLengthUnitsInput.option("m");
  beamLengthUnitsInput.option("cm");
  beamLengthUnitsInput.option("mm");
  beamLengthUnitsInput.selected("m");

  supportTypeInput = createSelect();
  supportTypeInput.position(170,60);
  supportTypeInput.size(140,20);
  supportTypeInput.option("None");
  supportTypeInput.option("Rolling Support");
  supportTypeInput.option("Fixed Support");
  supportTypeInput.option("Wall Support");
  supportTypeInput.selected("Rolling Support");

  newSupportDistance = createInput('0');
  newSupportDistance.position(50,130);
  newSupportDistance.size(40,12);

  //creating input Divs
  simpleSupportDiv = createDiv('<p>Enter support distance x from left side<p>');
  simpleSupportDiv.position(20,95);
  simpleSupportDiv.size(300,100);
  simpleSupportDiv.class('inputDiv');
  
  wallSupportDiv = createDiv("   Enter the side of the support");
  wallSupportDiv.position(20,95);
  wallSupportDiv.size(300,100);
  wallSupportDiv.class('inputDiv');

  // drawing beam
  fill('#27D1EB');
  strokeWeight(2);
  rect(400,350,borderWidth-800,100);
  line(400,570,400+borderWidth-800,570);
}

function draw() {
  // total length line
  strokeWeight(0);
  fill(0);
  textSize(16);
  text(beamLengthInput.value().concat(" ".concat(beamLengthUnitsInput.selected())),borderWidth/2-10,595);

  // changing displayed div for inputs
  if (supportTypeInput.value() == "Rolling Support" || supportTypeInput.value() == "Fixed Support") {
    if (simpleSupportDivShown == false) {
      simpleSupportDiv.show();
      wallSupportDiv.hide();
      simpleSupportDivShown = true;
      wallSupportDivShown = false;
    }
    newSupportDistance.show()
  }
  else if (supportTypeInput.value() == "Wall Support") {
    if (wallSupportDivShown == false) {
      simpleSupportDiv.hide();
      wallSupportDiv.show();
      wallSupportDivShown = true;
      simpleSupportDivShown = false;
    }   
  }
  else {
    simpleSupportDiv.hide();
    wallSupportDiv.hide();
    wallSupportDivShown = false;
    simpleSupportDivShown = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

The input box newSupportDistance is what gets hidden by the div simpleSupportDiv

Comment: Absolute positioning is probably not the way to go with this. I don't think p5 (and JS in general) is particularly well-suited to managing forms with so many inputs. I'd just use standard HTML inputs and a standard flow layout. Toss in a few change handlers or a form submit button where needed (light JS) and profit.